# Where to put a utility function in Angular

Tags: angular

This is just an example working with Angular, let say I need to use a function in the component, in this case the `getDay()` function will be called by an event.

```
getDay()  {
  switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
      day = "Sunday";
      break;
    case 1:
      day = "Monday";
      break;
    case 2:
       day = "Tuesday";
       break;
    case 3:
      day = "Wednesday";
      break;
    case 4:
      day = "Thursday";
      break;
    case 5:
      day = "Friday";
      break;
    case 6:
      day = "Saturday";
  }
}
```

Since I'm using Typescript, should I just create a shared folder inside components directory and inside it:

Create a component e.g: `formatDate.component.ts` with `export class FormateDateComponent` and just add my function there and import where I want?

What would be the best practice.

Comment: the best practice in my opinion is to have Utility service/class where you put your shared logic (and thats what the angular team recommends)

Comment: @RachidO I've never seen this recommendation of a utility service or class from the angular team. have a link?

Comment: @bryan60 https://angular.io/guide/architecture#services-and-dependency-injection , I call it Utiliy service but in the end it's just an injectable service

Comment: @RachidO I know what dependency injection is, I've never seen a rec from the angular team specifically for a utility service since angular v1 when they were more important.  The transition to TS/ES6 made them a little superfluous and cumbersome IMO as they're generally stateless and don't carry dependencies themselves. so a utilities.ts file accomplishes the same thing with less boilerplate and potentially less overhead and smaller bundles as you can only import needed functions rather than inject the whole class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways :-

1. create a static method in a class:-

```js
    export Class DateHelper {
       static getDay()  {
        switch (new Date().getDay()) {
             case 0:
             day = "Sunday";
             break;
             case 1:
             day = "Monday";
             break;
             case 2:
             day = "Tuesday";
             break;
             case 3:
             day = "Wednesday";
             break;
             case 4:
             day = "Thursday";
             break;
             case 5:
             day = "Friday";
             break;
             case 6:
             day = "Saturday";
           }
        }
      }
```

and can use it like DateHelper.getDay() directly.

2. way create a class and inherit it in component Foreg:-

```js
    export class AppComponent extends DateHelper {
       constructor(){
         super();
       }
       this.getDay();
    }
```

For normal methods like you have i would go with first approach.

Comment: @Askash Garg  how can I import the first option on angular using typscript, would be import DateHelper from './pathtoDateHelper.js',  than I need to add function to the constructure as I would do when working with service(dependency injection)? for example in the constructure(getDay: DateHelper ) and than just use the function this.getDay()?

Comment: just import the class. and use it like i gave above. not needed in constructor. just import on top and use.

Comment: the static class is really not needed. you can just `export function getDay() { ... }` in some `date-utlities.ts` file

Comment: agree with @bryan60 since in JS function is first class, it actually feels much more natural to do so than enforce everything in OOP style

Comment: I feel this answer can be misleading if you are looking for best practices. Particularly if you are doing an Angular project where you get a decent dependency injection system out of box. Do not use inheritance, use composition! If you stick to the `extends DateHelper` and then find out that you need a `CurrencyHelper` too in your component - you are out of luck. If you inject the class everything is fine (just create a service).
Static classes/methods come with another issue - they can't use dependencies, which makes expanding them hard as the project grows.

Answer (score 9):

When I have alike questions I look how guys from angular, material or rxjs or any other widely-used framework do. For your case it would be https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/sanitization/url_sanitizer.ts -- just create file for a feature and export function with descriptive name. Organizing code by features is ok. But not create bulk of everything (e.g. `utils.ts`), try organizing by feature.